# Creating a tag for "ZEIT Now" - a CLI for deployment

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I was looking for a tag to represent ZEIT's deployment CLI called [now](https://zeit.co/now). And I noticed a couple questions were tagged with [nowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nowjs) which appears to be a [dead project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14476943/266535).

I did notice there is a [zeit-pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeit-pkg) tag so should we make a [zeit-now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeit-now) tag?

I'm just not sure which tag name should be used because the company is called "ZEIT", the tool is published to npm as "[now](https://www.npmjs.com/package/now)", and the GitHub repo is "[now-cli](https://github.com/zeit/now-cli)".

What should the new tag be called?

Comment: ZEIT* ;) /length

Comment: @Qix I'm not sure I understand

Comment: ZEIT in all caps instead of Zeit :)

Comment: Fixed. You don't have to yell at me :P Also note that tags are all lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

I added a deprecated message to `nowjs`

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nowjs/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3408851

I added a new tag for `zeit-now`

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zeit-now/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3408848

Comment: Keep in mind, `nowjs` isn't necessary ZEIT's Now. Nowjs is a framework.

Comment: Correct. I only saw two questions that probably mean `zeit-now` so I added the tag. But it's hard to say if they `nowjs` tag should be removed because technically, it could be both. That being said, `nowjs` seems to no longer exist. So I think it would be confusing to keep the tag around for new questions.