# Synonymise [nowjs] with [zeit-now]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

In a [previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359174) I discovered there is a dead project called `nowjs`. The last usage was from 2012 and then the website went dark according to [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20121102071145/http://www.nowjs.com/).

I then noticed that the old website showed the usage as `var nowjs = require("now")` which means that it actually is the [now](https://www.npmjs.com/package/now) package on npm and was repurposed as ZEIT Now CLI.

Therefore, I propose that [nowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nowjs) and [zeit-now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeit-now) tags should be synonymized (the latter has the correct description) and the former is deprecated.

Comment: I don't think that's correct, because they are two different things (NowJS seems to be a now-dead socket.io-like library, while Now is a serverless platform).

Comment: I think the `now` package name was just handed over to ZEIT.

Comment: Correct, the `now` package name was handed over to ZEIT at the beginning of 2016 because NowJS died long before then in 2012. So there is no way to install the old NowJS and the website is dead. Yet people keep tagging `nowjs` when they mean `zeit-now`. Compare these 2 readmes and publish dates: https://www.npmjs.com/package/now/v/0.8.1 and https://www.npmjs.com/package/now/v/0.9.0

Comment: @grooveplex Would it be better to delete `nowjs` tag to prevent new questions?

Comment: I'm not sure, honestly.

Comment: The issue here seems to be because of the re-usage of the name [tag:nowjs] to mean a completely different thing (Zeit-Now), instead of the earlier one (the deprecated sockets library)? Do correct me if I am wrong. This calls for a rename of the old tag to something else, a disambiguation, rather than a synonym.  Renaming the tag as [tag:nowjs-sockets] or something should solve the problem.

Comment: @BhargavRao That might work or it might cause more confusion. If someone types in "now" to the tags, you don't get `zeit-now`. Instead you see `snow-leopard`, `no-www`, and several other options that are irrelevant. So the user sees nothing for "now" and the next thing they will likely try is "nowjs".

Comment: That can be solved by adding [nowjs] as a synonym, _after_ renaming the previous tag to [nowjs-sockets].

Comment: @BhargavRao I think that's a great idea!

Answer (score 2):

As I was mentioning in the comments, the problem at hand is that NowJS now is related to a different library, as opposed to what it was earlier. If this is the case, then adding [nowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nowjs) as a synonym for [zeit-now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeit-now) would be completely wrong, as it would just mix up all the questions together and you would have a hard time sorting out the questions related to the old library.

What would be an ideal situation here would be to:

1. Rename the [nowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nowjs) tag to [nowjs-sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nowjs-sockets), or some other relevant name for the old library.
2. Synonymize [nowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nowjs) (which would then be empty) to [zeit-now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeit-now).

I've based this answer on two important assumptions (a) that the earlier NowJS is completely deprecated. (b) that the current NowJS is actually ZEIT Now. It would be really helpful if a top user in [nowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nowjs) can confirm this.

Comment: I found the repository. The last commit was 2012 https://github.com/Flotype/now/commits/master